# React-Redux component giving TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm not exactly sure why it's complaining as I'm pretty sure I've hooked everything up correctly, my component class is as follows:

```
type SubmitLinkPopupProps =
    SubmitLinkPopupStore.SubmitLinkPopupState
    & typeof SubmitLinkPopupStore.actionCreators
    & RouteComponentProps<{}>;

type SubmitLinkPopupAllProps = SubmitLinkPopupProps;// & InputSubmitLinkProps;

export class SubmitLinkPopup extends Component<SubmitLinkPopupAllProps, SubmitLinkPopupStore.SubmitLinkPopupState>
{

    constructor(props: SubmitLinkPopupAllProps) {
        super(props);
        this.SubmitLink = this.SubmitLink.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.handleTextFieldChange = this.handleTextFieldChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleOpen = () => {
       //...
    };

    handleClose = () => {
       //...
    };

    handleTextFieldChange(e) {
         //...
    };

    SubmitLink() {
        //...
    }

    public render() {
        //...
    }
}

export default connect((state: Store.RootState) => state.submitLinkPopup, SubmitLinkPopupStore.actionCreators)(SubmitLinkPopup);
```

and the reducer looks like this:

```
export const actionCreators = {
       //...
}

type KnownAction = RequestSubmitLinkAction | CancelSubmitLinkAction;


const submitLinkPopupReducer: Reducer<SubmitLinkPopupState> =
    (state: SubmitLinkPopupState, incomingAction: KnownAction) => {
          //...
    }

    export default submitLinkPopupReducer;
```

It's all hooked up in the store:

```
export interface RootState {
submitLinkPopup: SubmitLinkPopupState
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
submitLinkPopup: submitLinkPopupReducer,
})

const rootStore = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(middleware),
)

export default rootStore
```

This was working in a previous React-Redux project I was working in, I'm not  sure what config might be missing which causes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on error message, the problem is `RouteComponentProps<{}>;` you need to change it to `RouteComponentProps<any>`